# How to solve a Redis sorted set draw?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm using Redis to handle users points rankings, I gotta:

1. Store users points
2. Obtain users ranking positions

So I'm using `zincrby` to update ranking position and then I'm using `zrevrangebyscore` for the top list, `zscore` and `zrevrank` to obtain all what I need.

So, when a draw case is present (and I actually have lots of that) I can't trust in Redis criteria to sort.

My winning criteria for draw cases is Date, where oldest is first. These are MongoDB ids which I'm storing, so I could actually retrieve the date from `_id`.

So, if I want to know the actual rank for a user

1. Obtain the points user achieved, maybe using `zrevrank`.
2. Obtain all the users with same points.
3. Consider upper and lower bounds.
4. Order users with same points by date obtained from Mongo ID.
5. Assign a position according to the rest of same points draw and the upper a and lower neighbors.

I will code all this with the default node.js driver, so it's Javascript code which we're talking about.

How can any Redis command help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a Sorted Set's score can be a floating point value, uou can store a combination of the timestamp and the ranking in it and use the decimal point as your "delimiter". That will give you both the ranking that's also based on the date.

Example, if my ranking is 50 and the time stamp now is 1438594593, the score in the set would be 50.856140541 according to the following "formula":

score = ranking + (1 - timestamp / 10^10)

Comment: Thanks,  the caveat of your suggestion is that for Redis the newest would be in a higher position, and I need orders to get higher